# datepicker dialog using DialogFragment for multiple activities

Tags: android-dialogfragment, datepickerdialog

I need to use DatePicker dialog using the new DialogFragment class for multiple activities.
I am having more than two activities using datepicker and time picker. I succeeded using the example in developer.android.com for Dialog Fragment for single activity.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    String date;
    Bundle bundle;
    Intent in;
    //private View v;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),(Pickup)getActivity(), year, month, day);

}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

If I use that I have to write different DialogFragment classes for each activities. Is there any solution like using switch case provided in this example?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addnewreminder);
    initialize();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    OnClickListener listenerDate = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    };
    editTextDate.setOnClickListener(listenerDate);

}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    editTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);

}


private void updateDisplay() {
    currentDate = new StringBuilder().append(day).append(".")
            .append(month + 1).append(".").append(year).toString();

    Log.i("DATE", currentDate);
}

OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int j, int k) {

        year = i;
        month = j;
        day = k;
        updateDisplay();
        editTextDate.setText(currentDate);
    }
};



@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateSetListener, year, month,
                day);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I wanted to use an AlertDialog Dialog Fragment in multiple activities.

Here is my DialogFragment which is made of an Alert Dialog. In newInstance I require the title and the activity. Title is going to be in string.xml. Activity is going to be 1 or 2 based on what I say when I create a new MyDialog. I pass both of those to the Bundle "args" using putInt.(You can also use putString if you are more comfortable with that. Then in the onCreateDialog, I pull both the title and the activity name from getArguments() and use the activity to decided in a switch which action to take. And of course based on which Activity I am trying to do the .doPositiveClick or .doNegativeClick, I have to cast which Activity to perform the function in. Using this method, I can make minimal changes to MyDialog class and use it in other Activities.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

static MyDialog newInstance(int title, int activity) {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    args.putInt("activity", activity);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
    int activity = getArguments().getInt("activity");
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle(title)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            switch (activity){

            case 1:
                ((MyActivity) getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                break;
            case 2:
                ((AnotherActivity) getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    )
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            switch (activity) {
            case 1:
                ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                break;
            case 2:
                ((AnotherActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                break;
                    }
                }
            }
    )
    .create();
}
```

}

Here is where I call on my alert dialog. This can be used in two different Activities. "MyActivity" and "AnotherActivity"

```
    void showDeleteDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialog.newInstance(
            R.string.myDialogTitle, 1);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

am to late but i hope this answer will help some one in future :
i do'it by passing DIALOG_ID argument by setArgument method for each activity and in dialogFragment check the DIALOG_ID value and set pickerDialog for each one 
ex:
    {

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (dialog_id == 1) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
    } else {
        return new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), ontimeSet, hour, minute, false);
    }
}

}
```

like this snippet example to under stand it more clear