# DialogFragment with multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialogfragment

I used the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) to create a dialogfragment. The code is :

```
public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
    MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}}
```

the dialogfragment here is associated with only the activity FragmentAlertDialog. Is there any way to associate it with multiple activities? I have my calling activity name in onCreateDialog by passing it through setArguements(). Any way to use it ? I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114436/datepicker-dialog-using-dialogfragment-for-multiple-activities) and was hoping for a confirmation/better way.

Comment: @gunar because it would reduce my code drastically..i have 10 activities, all needing a dialogfragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a `FragmentAlerDialog` activity, you could define somewhere an interface (by somewhere I mean either a `public static interface` in DialogFragment class, or a separate `public interface` Java file), and any `Activity` that wishes to display the dialog could implement this interface.

One common practice that I use is to have a root `Activity` for all my project activities. Make that root activity implement that interface and then you can display that `DialogFragment` from anywhere.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks ! but I did not get what you mean by 'project activities' ?

Comment: Suppose you have 3 activities in your project (A, B & C). Instead of extending directly from `Activity`/`FragmentActivity` they could extend from a `MyRootActivity` and that could extend from `Activity`/`FragmentActivity`. Make that `MyRootActivity` implement the interface you need and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just post what edits I made in my code, all credits to @gunar,

create new DialogImplement.java as:

```
package com.example.test;
public interface DialogImplement
{

    public void doPositiveClick();

}
```

Add `@Override` in activity code before the implementation of `doPositiveClick()`, for eg:

```
@Override
public void doPositiveClick() 
{
    //do what you want to do

}
```

make sure your activity implements DialogImplement, and modify code in the question as:

```
((DialogImplement)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(); //Or negative click code
```

Hope this helps..Cheers :]